# trying to connect to the mysql server on tomcat6: java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, mysql, exception, tomcat6

I having some trouble to connect to my mysql server from my java/scala worker.

Here is the stack trace I got:

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor25.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[indexer-worker-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121) ~[indexer-worker-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:355) ~[indexer-worker-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2479) ~[indexer-worker-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2516) ~[indexer-worker-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301) ~[indexer-worker-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834) ~[indexer-worker-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[indexer-worker-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor10.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[indexer-worker-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416) ~[indexer-worker-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317) ~[indexer-worker-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:620) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:200) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at listen$IndexTransactionWorkerImpl.run(listen.scala:38) [indexer-worker-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at net.greghaines.jesque.worker.WorkerImpl.execute(WorkerImpl.java:630) [indexer-worker-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at net.greghaines.jesque.worker.WorkerImpl.process(WorkerImpl.java:600) [indexer-worker-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at net.greghaines.jesque.worker.WorkerImpl.poll(WorkerImpl.java:491) [indexer-worker-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at net.greghaines.jesque.worker.WorkerImpl.run(WorkerImpl.java:230) [indexer-worker-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [na:1.6.0_27]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql-vip
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1229) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1156) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1092) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:249) ~[indexer-worker-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:305) ~[indexer-worker-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

It works fine until a certain point, the worker is unable to resolve the host. If I restart the worker, it is working again.

Important thing: I am able to ping the host from the machine!

I tried to use ipv4 instead with `Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` but I got the same error with the ipv4 stack.

I don't have any clue so far! Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Did you already try with the hostname instead of the ip address?

Comment: @Ankit the ip address is dynamic, I can only use the hostname which is mysql-vip (pingable from the machine)

Comment: Have you tried with a fully-qualified hostname instead of just "mysql-vip"? There might be a problem with the domain search path.

Comment: Ok, just to confirm you are using this pattern right ??jdbc:mysql://[host][,failoverhost...][:port]/[database]

Comment: @Ankit yes we are using the right pattern

Comment: @chrylis mysql-vip is in the resolver conf, so it should work even if it is not a fully-qualified hostname.

Moreover, the host is reached and at a certain time (random), we have this exception (and meanwhile we are able to ping it)

Comment: I was just about to ask you to check the resolver conf file for the host entry. But alas!!! this is indeed an interesting problem.

Comment: @icl1c Don't assume that the `resolv.conf` is getting used appropriately; Firefox in particular is rather notorious for going off and doing its own thing regarding DNS, and as the JRE code for DNS is native, I'm not sure if it delegates everything. If you connect intermittently, I'm suspicious of your DNS server. (Also, remember that `resolv.conf` doesn't have host entries; it lists the nameservers. Be sure you mean that `/etc/hosts` has a static entry if that's what you're intending.)

Comment: @chrylis in the resolv.conf file, there is the DNS ip. And it's resolving "mysql-vip" perfectly via a ping (even if the worker is failing)

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for this Well it might happen if you do not manage your connection pool properly. in the sense if you are maintaining a connection pool yourself (or say using apache dhcp or something), then either you have too many connections open that everything gets blocked or not managing the resources well.

Another reason can be this: (It happened with us over a month back). When too many long queries were being executed at once. We did some optimizations on procedure side and things started working (By disabling read locks).